# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Error For Array That Shouldn't Be Going Off Bounds

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code:

```
public class Test {

  static private int arraySize;
  public Test(int arrayS){
      arraySize = arrayS;
     
  }
  int []ma = new int[arraySize];
  public static void main(String[] args){
 

  }
  public void increment(){
    int count = arraySize - 1;
    ma[count - 1] += 1;
    while(count!= 0){
        if(ma[count] > 9){
            ma[count] =0;
            ma[count - 1] +=1;
        }
    count -=1;
        }
    if(ma[0] > 9){
    ma[0] = 0;

    }

    }

  }




class Trial
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Test z = new Test(2);
    System.out.println(z);  

    z.increment();
    System.out.println(z);  

 }
}
```

There is a class called test and another called trial. Whenever the main method inside of Trial attempts to build test which has an array there is an index out of bounds exception that comes up. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Theres a lot of missing code buddy... Please put the whole code so we can try and understand eg your Test constructor is missing

Comment: Assign the array inside the constructor. I think the issue is happening due to the size being static and getting initialized before. That pretty much leads to the array getting initialized with size 0

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no any parameterised constructor in your Test class. How you create object  using `new Test(2);`

Secondly  you initialize globally `int []ma = new int[arraySize];` 
This time arraySize having value zero.

Put `ma=new int[arraySize];` in your constructor after you set value of `arraySize` by `arrayS` value

Comment: Sorry there was a bit of an error while writing it here, the constructor should be there now.

Answer (score 0):

Since arraySize is a static instance variable, it will be initialized to 0 when your program is started and hence the ma has a size of 0

That is why when you access ma[0] you get an error

To resolve it, you need to initialize ma in your constructor

```
static private int arraySize;
  public Test(int arrayS){
      arraySize = arrayS;
      ma = new int[arrayS];
  }
  int []ma;
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize arraySize and ma inline. So arraySize is initialized with 0 (not NULL) and then your array gets initialized with a capacity of 0. You should initialize your array within the constructor.